# Set min and max breakpoints with single variable with LESS?

Tags: less

Im trying set a media query breakpoint with LESS so I can have something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  // something
}
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  // something
}
```

I want a single place to control the breakpoint. The following isnt working. Is this just a syntax issue or am I going about this the wrong way?

```
@breakpoint: 1000;

@breakpoint-max: @breakpoint;
@breakpoint-min: @breakpoint + 1;

@media (max-width: @breakpoint-max) {
  // something
}
@media (min-width: @breakpoint-min) {
  // something
}
```

Comment: What happens? What's the generated source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure why the media query to try to compile should not work, except for the missing unit as mentioned by @SLaks already.

In you example situation you can apply 'mobile first':

```
@breakpoint: 1000px;

@breakpoint-max: @breakpoint;
@breakpoint-min: (@breakpoint + 1);

//something
p {
color:red;
@media (min-width: @breakpoint-min) {
  // something
  color:green;
}
}
```

The above compiles into the code shown below by default:

```
p {
  color: red;
}
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  p {
    color: green;
  }
}
```

The color is always red, unless the screen width is wider that 1000 px.
Also notice the brackets in `@breakpoint-min: (@breakpoint + 1);`. The requirement of brackets in this case depend on the `sm` option:

> -sm=on|off               Turns on or off strict math, where in strict mode, math.
>
> --strict-math=on|off     Requires brackets. This option may default to on and then
>                           be removed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You never specified a unit.

You need to set your variable to `1000px`.